# PHP + MySQL - Echo variables after fetching multiple foreign data from table

Tags: php, mysql

I've done this :-

```
    $qry=mysql_query("SELECT client.resID, menu.name FROM client INNER JOIN menu ON   
    client.resID = menu.resID WHERE client.resID = $resID");

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

    echo $row['name'];

}

?>
<form action="client_admin_post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">


<p>Services &nbsp;&nbsp;:
<label for="cat"></label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />
</p>


<p align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

I'm building a php form that fetch data from MySQL table. It's for editing the data in MySQL table. The problem is now, let's say, there are many menus in a restaurant. So, in this case, there are many rows in 'menus' MysQL table with same restaurantID(pk). I need to fetch all the menus to 5 fields. With this code, I can only fetch a menu only. How could I do that?

Thank you :D
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to loop over your result set. Something like this should work

```
$names = array(); //array to store all names

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) { // loop as long as there are more results
    $names[] = $row['name'];  // push to the array
}

print_r($names);    // $names array now contains all names
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the id so there are not duplicate ids. If your name input does need an id, it would be best to add an incremental variable for each loop. e.g. "name1", "name2", etc...

```
<form action="client_admin_post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    <?php
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT client.resID, menu.name FROM client INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.resID WHERE client.resID = $resID");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
    {
        ?>
        <p>
            Services &nbsp;&nbsp;:
            <label for="cat"></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <p align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I got this Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/makanman/public_html/nonhalal/client_admin.php on line 35 after trying the code. It's the while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) row.  Sorry for asking too much but I've no idea how it's gonna work. Thank you very much :D

Comment: try printing out the sql query by taking the sql out of the `mysql_query` function, and putting it in its own varaible. `e.g. $sql = "SELECT client.resID, menu.name FROM client INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.resID WHERE client.resID = $resID"`, then use `print($sql);` see if the query prints out as expected. If it does, then try manually copy and pasting that into you database and see if you get the results or an error.